# How to test Telegram bot using rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, telegram-bot

I'm building a simple bot, and I need to test the following method, but I run into what looks like an infinite loop no matter what I do.

The method I want to test

```
def main_method(token)
@id_array = []
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
  bot.listen do |message|
    @id_array.push(message.chat.id) unless @id_array.include?(message.chat.id)
    case message.text
    when '/quote'
      quote, author = RandomQuote.new.get_quote!
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "#{quote}\n\t- Author: #{author}")
    when '/joke'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "What's your name?")
      bot.listen do |name|
        if name
          @joke = Jokes.new.random_joke(name.text)
          break
        end
      end
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: @joke.to_s)
    when '/help'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: 'Type /joke to receive a custom joke with your name')
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: 'Type /quote to receive an inspirational quote')
    end
  end
end
```

end

My bot is working and doing it's task, I just need any testcase to prove that it's functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, it's not kind "infinite loop", it is event-listener (`bot.listen`), it's kind of polling some of the ports to get the some of the messages, and then fires the react on this event.

So, you need to split this method to small chunks with OOP logic, because there are huge of cases for one specific method, and then test each chunk as a dedicated class with mocks usage.

To handle initialize you can use VCR cassette to stub real request into API, and replace token to your testing token.

For example, we can mock main_method to be sure that: listener is called, like this:

```
class MyRubyBot
  def main_method(token)
    ...
  end
end


around do |example|
  VCR.use_cassette('telegram_bot') do
    example.run
  end
end

it 'fires run on telegram bot' do
  expect(telegram_bot).to receive(:run).with("YOU_TEST_TOKEN")
  MyRubyBot.new.main_method("YOU_TEST_TOKEN")
end

it 'fires listener' do
  expect_any_instance_of(Telegram::Bot::Client).to receive(:listen)
  MyRubyBot.new.main_method("YOU_TEST_TOKEN")
end
```

Then you need to put logic from each `when` into dedicated class, for example:

```
class QuoteMessage
  attr_accessor :bot, :message

  def initialize(bot:, message:)
    self.bot = bot
    self.message = message
  end

  def send_response
    quote, author = RandomQuote.new.get_quote!
    bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "#{quote}\n\t- Author: #{author}")
  end
end
class QuoteMessage
  attr_accessor :bot, :message, :joke

  def initialize(bot:, message:)
    self.bot = bot
    self.message = message
  end

  def send_response
    bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "What's your name?")
    bot.listen do |name|
      if name
        @joke = Jokes.new.random_joke(name.text)
        break
      end
    end
    bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: @joke.to_s)
  end
end
class HelpMessage
  attr_accessor :bot, :message

  def initialize(bot:, message:)
    self.bot = bot
    self.message = message
  end

  def send_response
    bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: 'Type /joke to receive a custom joke with your name')
    bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: 'Type /quote to receive an inspirational quote')
  end
end
```

Great, now we can test each of class separately for mock bot class as anything, for simple example:

```
describe QuoteMessage do
  let(:bot) { double }
  let(:api) { double }
  let(:message) { double }

  it 'fires send_message' do
    expect(bot).to receive(:api).and_return(api)
    expect(api).to receive(:send_message).with(...)
    described_class.new(bot: bot, message: message).send_response
  end
end
# ... same logic for other classes
```

almost there! now we can a bit refactor your main_method with new MessageHandler class, something like this:

```
def main_method(token)
  @id_array = []
  Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
    bot.listen do |message|
      @id_array.push(message.chat.id) unless @id_array.include?(message.chat.id)
      MessageHandler.new(bot: bot, message: message).handle_message
    end
  end
end

class MessageHandler
  attr_accessor :bot, :message

  def initialize(bot:, message:)
    self.bot = bot
    self.message = message
  end

  def handle_message
    case message.text
    when '/quote'
      QuoteMessage.new(bot: bot, message: message).send_response
    when '/joke'
      joke_message = JokeMessage.new(bot: bot, message: message)
      joke_message.send_response
      @joke = joke_message.joke
    when '/help'
      HelpMessage.new(bot: bot, message: message).send_response
    end
  end
end
```

so, now we can testing fires of `MessageHandler` by `and_yield` approach:

```
it 'fires MessageHandler' do
  message = 'any_message'
  expect(bot).to receive(:listen).and_yield(MessageHandler.new(bot: bot, message: message))
  MyRubyBot.new.main_method("YOU_TEST_TOKEN")
end
```

at least, we need to test MessageHandler, which now should be pretty easy, for example:

```
describe MessageHandler do
  subject { described_class.new(bot: bot, message: message) }
  let(:bot) { double }
  let(:api) { double }

  context 'when quote' do
    let(:message) { '/quote' }
    let(:quote_message) { instance_double QuoteMessage }

    it 'fires QuoteMessage instance' do
      expect(QuoteMessage).to receive(:new).with(bot: bot, message: message).and_return quote_message 
      expect(quote_message).to receive(:send_response) 
      subject.handle_message
    end
  end
end
```

surly, I could be wrong with some details, but overall I wanted to put the approach.

JFYI: try to ask more specific questions, since it looks like you have a task here, and you decided to put it in the same form here, so, it's not the best way, that why many ignore it. I hope it helps, take care!